# Is there an XPath expression to grab a value that's nested within a script tag

Tags: html, xpath

My goal is to write an XPath expression to retrieve the value `thevalueiwant` from the following script.

```html
<script>
  var meta = {
    "product": {
      "id": 1234,
      "variants": [{
        "price": 12345,
        "target": "thevalueiwant"
      }]
    },
  };
</script>
```

I am able to navigate to the script using the expression `//script[9]` I have also tried using contains like `//*[contains(text(),'target')]`

I'm not sure if getting the javascript values declared within the script is possible.

Comment: It depends on the circumstances you are in (which programming language and tools you use) how to deal with this. If you say what you're using, I might be able to give you a pointer.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the response, I'm using Python. I'm building a web scraper with Scrapy

Comment: I see... well you might want to look into Selenium with a headless browser instead. This way you get full programmatic control over a complete browser that does all the things for you (session cookies, local storage, Javascript parsing, Ajax, you name it). You can grab your JS value with that and it's the more capable tool overall. Scrapy is always limited to the raw HTML source code the server sends and misses many details.

Comment: @Tomalak Perfect, I shall check that out, Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My goal is to write an XPath expression to retrieve the value thevalueiwant from the following script.

You can't. XPath is for navigating the DOM. From the DOM's point of view, the script source code is just plain text, like any other plain text in your HTML.

The browser treats `<script>` differently from other plain text, though - it gives the source code block to the JavaScript parser, which can make sense of it.

If you want to solve this task *properly*, you need to do the same thing. Grab the script source (e.g. with XPath), pass it to a JS parser, and search the abstract syntax tree that you receive for the value you want to extract.